# Powershell Regex help in extracting text between strings

Tags: regex, powershell

i Have an arguments like the one below which i pass to powershell script

```
-arg1 -abc -def -arg2 -ghi -jkl -arg3 -123 -234
```

Now i need to extract three strings without any whitespace

```
string 1: "-abc -def" 

string 2: "-ghi -jkl"

string 3: "-123 -234"
```

i figured this expression could do it. But this doesnt seem to work.

```
$args -match '-arg1(?'arg1'.*?) -arg3(?'arg3'.*?) -arg3(?'arg3'.*)'.
```

THis should return $matches['arg1'] etc. So whats wrong in above expression. Why do i get an error as shown below

```
runScript.ps1 -arg1 -abc -def -arg2 -ghi -jkl -arg3 -123 -234

Unexpected token 'arg1'.*?) -arg2
(?'arg2'.*?) -arg3 (?'arg3'.*)'' in
expression or statement. At
G:\powershell\tools\powershell\runTest.ps1:1
char:71
+ $args -match '-arg1 (?'arg1'.*?) -arg2 (?'arg2'.*?) -arg3 (?'arg3'.*)' <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (arg1'.*?) -arg2...g3
(?'arg3'.*)':String) [],
ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

and also the second question is how do i make `arg1` or `arg2` or `arg3` optional?

The argument to script  can be

```
-arg2 -def -ghi.
```

I'll take some default values for `arg(1|2|3)` that is not mentioned.

Thanks

Comment: If you run the script like `runScript.ps1 -arg1 -abc -def -arg2 -ghi -jkl -arg3 -123 -234` it means that you specifies parameters $arg1, $abc, $def, $arg2, .... Could you show the param(..) section of your script?

Comment: In the script i call an external exe with $args as argument. That exe gets called correctly with these -arg1 -abc -def arguments. Now the problem is I need to call three different exe with each of them having arguments that follows -arg1, -arg2.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the stack overflow syntax highlighter already spoils it for you: you're double-using the ' character; for named groups, and for the entire string.

I can't try as i dont have PS on this box, but what about:

```
$args -match '-arg1(?<arg1>.*?) -arg2(?<arg2>.*?) -arg3(?<arg3>.*)'
```

?

additionally, i would replace the spaces with `\s+`, so that multiple whitespace characters between the parameters are also allowed.

Comment: thanks .when i do that, no matches return. echo $matches[0] gives an error saying that "cannot index to a null array"